# F# - Pipeline with tupled parameters

Tags: f#

Is it possible to somehow use a pipeline to pass in the last argument of a method with tupled parameters?

An example:

```
// Member to call

static member Property (expr:Expr<'a -> string>, cfg:EntityInfo<'a>) = cfg.Property expr

// My curry function

let curry f x y = f (x,y)

// My EntityInfo<FileUpload>

let entityInfo = EF.Entity<FileUpload> modelBuilder
```

I want to be able to call it like:

```
entityInfo |> curry EF.Property <@ fun z -> z.Path @>
```

instead of

```
EF.Property(<@ fun z -> z.Path @>, entityInfo)
```

Comment: What you have looks good at a glance, does it not work?  What is the error?

Comment: @Brian, "A unique overload for method 'Property' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window). A type annotation may be needed."

Comment: Ah, yes, overloading, the bugaboo of type inference.  I don't think there's a way to make it work with this syntax for an overloaded method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that this is a simplified version of your problem (although you're excluding too much code to be sure):

```
type T() = class end

type S =
    static member Method(_:int, T) = 'c'
    static member Method(_:string, T) = false

let curry f x y = f(x,y)

// won't work
T() |> curry S.Method 1
```

As Brian mentions, overloading doesn't play nicely with type inference.  In particular, since F#'s type inference works left-to-right, the compiler does not use the fact that `1` is an `int` when trying to do the member lookup for `S.Method`, which means that it can't identify the correct overload.  As I see it, you have a few options:

1. Use distinct method names.  Is there a reason that you have to use `Property` to refer to multiple different operations?  Would it be much worse to use `StringProperty`, `IntProperty`, etc. for each overload?  In general, overloading makes life harder for the compiler (and often for human maintainers, too).  As an aside, I don't like the idea of naming a method `Property`, anyway...
2. Use explicit type parameters on `curry`, and specify them.  E.g.

   ```
   let curry<'a,'b,'c> f (x:'a) (y:'b) : 'c = f(x,y)
   entityInfo |> curry<Expr<_ -> string>,_,_> EF.Property <@ fun z -> z.Path @>
   ```
3. Explicitly indicate the type of `EF.Property`:

   ```
   entityInfo |> curry (EF.Property: Expr<_ -> string> * _ -> _) <@ fun z -> z.Path @>
   ```

Of course, these last two options aren't very concise, so they may defeat the purpose of using the pipelined style.

Comment: My first thought was to give them names like `StringProperty` and `IntProperty`, but I thought that was bad practice since most people seems to prefer overloads instead, but its not? - And as you say then the last two options you gave isnt what I would call ehmm... neat ;p

Comment: @ebb - it depends...  People typically use overloading when it is possible to call a method with a subset of arguments rather than the full list - when using C# 3 or lower, this made sense, but now using optional parameters is probably better.  Using overloading when a method can take two completely different types is less common, and I'd almost always try to avoid it in favor of using more descriptive names.  This is particularly true when using F#, since as you've seen overloading can wreak havoc with type inference.

Answer (score 0):

It is because it is counting entity info as an member of EF.Propery method instead of curry method, you should use

```
entityInfo |> curry (EF.Property) (<@ fun z -> z.Path @>)
```

Comment: That throws an exception: "The member or object constructor 'Property' taking 2 arguments are not accessible from this code location. All accessible versions of method 'Property' take 2 arguments."

Comment: hmm.. It now throws: "A unique overload for method 'Property' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. The available overloads are shown below (or in the Error List window). A type annotation may be needed" - however the overload should be correct.

Comment: Please output the error you get on which overload it is trying to take

Comment: "Type constraint mismatch. The type      EntityInfo<FileUpload>     is not compatible with type     Quotations.Expr<('a -> string)>     The type 'EntityInfo<FileUpload>' is not compatible with the type 'Quotations.Expr<('a -> string)>'"

Comment: Yes, it has not interpreted the FileUpload in the Quotation, you should do the following `let expr:Expr<FileUpload -> string> = <@ fun z -> z.Path @>` and then call this: `let _ = entityInfo |> curry (EF.Property) (expr)`

Comment: Weird, but it is not because of the currying, try calling the same method without curry and you should get the same result